# Why is my autoSave function not working?

Tags: notebooks, user-interface, save, scheduling, autosave

This is not asking how to set up a timed recurring autoSave so please do not flag as already answered. The following should work but it doesn't and I cannot figure out why. While running this I made certain the function remained visible on screen the entire time.

```
autoSave[min_ : 30] :=
  Dynamic[
   Refresh[NotebookSave[]; DateString[], UpdateInterval -> min*60]];

autoSave[1];
```

Comment: You are hiding the `Dynamic` output, so it will never need to be displayed. This means the content of the `Dynamic` is never called. I'd suggest you look at the task scheduling stuff, which is explicitly designed for recurring tasks like this one (without the need to keep something visible on-screen)

Comment: I am not sure what that has to do with the question here? If you have a follow-up question, please ask it as a new question

Comment: @LukasLang okay will do